# Postfix stops delivering mail

Tags: postfix

My server crashed and after that postfix won't deliver mails anymore.
In the logging the following messages appear:

```
Dec 26 21:21:00 xx postfix/smtpd[14725]: connect from localhost[::1]
Dec 26 21:21:00 xx postfix/smtpd[14725]: warning: lookup jaap@xxxx.nl, NIS domain xxx.nl, map mail.aliases: internal yp server or client error
Dec 26 21:21:00 xx postfix/smtpd[14725]: warning: nis:mail.aliases lookup error for "jaap@xxxx.nl"
Dec 26 21:21:00 xx postfix/smtpd[14725]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[::1]: 451 4.3.0 <jaap@xxxx.nl>: Temporary lookup failure; from=<monit@gassoon.xxx.nl> to=<jaap@xxxx.nl> proto=ESMTP helo=<gassoon>
```

Yesterday (when postfix ran without problems) I saw a log line:

```
warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
```

Why thinks postfix now that it should use NIS?

The output of postfinger:

```
postfinger - postfix configuration on Sun 26 Dec 2021 09:32:18 PM CET
version: 1.30

Warning: postfinger output may show private configuration information,
such as ip addresses and/or domain names which you do not want to show
to the public.  If this is the case it is your responsibility to modify
the output to hide this private information.  [Remove this warning with
the --nowarn option.]
--System Parameters--
mail_version = 3.4.14
hostname = gassoon
uname = Linux gassoon 4.19.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.208-1 (2021-09-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux

--Packaging information--
looks like this postfix comes from deb package: postfix-3.4.14-0+deb10u1

--main.cf non-default parameters--
alias_database = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-aliases.cf
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
compatibility_level = 2
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = $myhostname, [removed server names]
myhostname = [removed server]
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = gassoon[removed domain]
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/gassoon[removed domain]/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/gassoon[removed domain]/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-aliases.cf

--master.cf--
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
   -o smtpd_etrn_restrictions=reject
   -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes 
   -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

-- end of postfinger output --
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pff, searching for hours and found

`postconf` has an output line:

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, nis:....
```

I added a line in `main.cf`

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
```

And the mail floods like a charm.

Comment: Please accept your answer if it solved your issue.